# Python Transcrypt addEventListener

Tags: python, addeventlistener, transcrypt

I have written a Python program for translation with Transcrypt to Javascript.
I can not get the addEventListener function to work. Any ideas?

Here is the code as dom7.py:

```
class TestSystem:

def __init__ (self):
    self.text = 'Hello, DOM!'
    self.para = 'A new paragraph'
    self.textblock = 'This is an expandable text block.'
    self.button1 = document.getElementById("button1")
    self.button1.addEventListener('mousedown', self.pressed)

def insert(self):,
    document.querySelector('output').innerText = self.text
    # document.querySelector('test').innerText = "Test"+self.button1+":"

def pressed(self):
    container = document.getElementById('textblock')
    newElm = document.createElement('p')
    newElm.innerText = self.para
    container.appendChild(newElm)

testSystem = TestSystem()
```

And here follows the corresponding dom7.html for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<script src="__javascript__/dom7.js"></script>
<title>Titel</title>
</head>
<body onload=dom7.testSystem.insert()>
<button id="button1">Click me</button><br>
<main>
    <h1>DOM examples</h1>
    <p>Testing DOM</p>
    <p>
        <output></output>
    </p>
  <p>
    <test>Test String:</test>
  </p>

  <div id="textblock">
    <p>This is an expandable text block.</p>
  </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `TestSystem` constructor is called before the DOM tree is ready. There are **three** ways to deal with this, **the last of which is the best**.

The first way is to include your script after you populated your body:

```
class TestSystem:

    def __init__ (self):
        self.text = 'Hello, DOM!'
        self.para = 'A new paragraph'
        self.textblock = 'This is an expandable text block.'
        self.button1 = document.getElementById("button1")
        self.button1.addEventListener('mousedown', self.pressed)

    def insert(self):
        document.querySelector('output').innerText = self.text
        # document.querySelector('test').innerText = "Test"+self.button1+":"

    def pressed(self):
        container = document.getElementById('textblock')
        newElm = document.createElement('p')
        newElm.innerText = self.para
        container.appendChild(newElm)

testSystem = TestSystem()
```

and:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <title>Titel</title>
    </head>
    <body onload=dom7.testSystem.insert()>
        <button id="button1">Click me</button><br>
        <main>
            <h1>DOM examples</h1> 
            <p>
                Testing DOM
            </p>           
            <p>
                <output></output>
            </p>           
            <p>
                <test>Test String:</test>
            </p>
            <div id="textblock">
                <p>This is an expandable text block.</p>
            </div>

            <script src="__javascript__/dom7.js"></script>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Still your `insert` function may be called too early, so may not work.

The second way is to include the script at the beginning and call an initialization function to connect event handlers to the DOM:

```
class TestSystem:

    def __init__ (self):
        self.text = 'Hello, DOM!'
        self.para = 'A new paragraph'
        self.textblock = 'This is an expandable text block.'
        self.button1 = document.getElementById("button1")
        self.button1.addEventListener('mousedown', self.pressed)

    def insert(self):
        document.querySelector('output').innerText = self.text
        # document.querySelector('test').innerText = "Test"+self.button1+":"

    def pressed(self):
        container = document.getElementById('textblock')
        newElm = document.createElement('p')
        newElm.innerText = self.para
        container.appendChild(newElm)

def init ():
    testSystem = TestSystem()
```

and:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <script src="__javascript__/dom7.js"></script>

        <title>Titel</title>
    </head>
    <body onload=dom7.testSystem.insert()>
        <button id="button1">Click me</button><br>
        <main>
            <h1>DOM examples</h1> 
            <p>
                Testing DOM
            </p>           
            <p>
                <output></output>
            </p>           
            <p>
                <test>Test String:</test>
            </p>
            <div id="textblock">
                <p>This is an expandable text block.</p>
            </div>
            <script>dom7.init ();</script>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Still there is a possibility that some browsers call the initialization function before the page is loaded, although this is rare. In addition to this the `insert` method is again called too early.

**Third and best way**, to solve both problems, is to run your initialization after a page load event, and call `insert` after you create your `testSystem`, so e.g. in the initalization function:

```
class TestSystem:

    def __init__ (self):
        self.text = 'Hello, DOM!'
        self.para = 'A new paragraph'
        self.textblock = 'This is an expandable text block.'
        self.button1 = document.getElementById("button1")
        self.button1.addEventListener('mousedown', self.pressed)

    def insert(self):
        document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = self.text
        # document.querySelector('test').innerText = "Test"+self.button1+":"

    def pressed(self):
        container = document.getElementById('textblock')
        newElm = document.createElement('p')
        newElm.innerText = self.para
        container.appendChild(newElm)

def init ():
    testSystem = TestSystem()
    testSystem.insert ()
```

and:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <script src="__javascript__/dom7.js"></script>

        <title>Titel</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="dom7.init ();">
        <button id="button1">Click me</button><br>
        <main>
            <h1>DOM examples</h1> 
            <p>
                Testing DOM
            </p>           
            <p>
                <output></output>
            </p>           
            <p>
                <test>Test String:</test>
            </p>
            <div id="textblock">
                <p>This is an expandable text block.</p>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot. For my own study with Transcrypt I have uploaded several examples to github in order to introduce myself to Python and Javascript via Transcrypt. You may use these files if you find them useful for a beginner´s tutorial. If I find the time I will try to complete them more: [https://github.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples](https://github.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples)

Comment: That could be very useful! Will take a good look once they're ready.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your mondrian example in the tutorial section and I saw that there is also a very simple way to attach the addEventListener to a document after it has loaded. You can use the DOMContentLoaded attribute in the header of the html doc for doing so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script src="__javascript__/addEventListener_example1.js"></script>
        <script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addEventListener_example1.init)</script>
        <title>Titel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="button1">Click me</button><br>
        <main>
            <h1>DOM examples</h1> 
            <p>
                Testing DOM
            </p>           
            <p>
                <output></output>
            </p>           
            <p>
                <test>Test String:</test>
            </p>
            <div id="textblock">
                <p>This is an expandable text block.</p>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the code for addEventListener_example1.py would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def init():
    insert()

def insert():
    document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = 'Hello, DOM!'
    button1 = document.getElementById("button1")
    button1.addEventListener('mousedown', pressed)

def pressed():
    para = 'A new paragraph'
    container = document.getElementById('textblock')
    newElm = document.createElement('p')
    newElm.innerText = para
    container.appendChild(newElm)
```